# Как реализовать вот такое с Crop Image

Tags: android

В общем нужно сделать crop для изображения

Должно выглядеть вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Штука в том, что должна быть возможность двигать не кроп окно как в стандартных имплементациях, а картинка на бекграунде, а окно должно быть статическое и находиться с одном месте как на скриншоте

Вот нашел такую либ https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop

в которой этот подход реализован, но там совсем нет возможности кастомизировать вью и нет возможнсти кроп окно сделать овальным. Не обязательно, чтобы результат кропнутого изображение было круглым(так как битмап можно вырезать по квадрату если не заморачиваться)

Если есть у кого то реализация дайте пример или может кто то встречал такую либу как мне нужна

Я вот думаю даже свое кастомное вью написать там по сути нужно сделать, чтоб `ImageView` было подвижным и кропать его на том месте где кроп окно. Но мне кажется это не так просто как кажется

Comment: Использовать что-нибудь типо glide, для перемещения, масштабирования картинки пальцем и получать координаты центра видимой части картинки, как центра кроп окна, для последующей обработки картинки?

Comment: @KostyaM я чет не совсем понял